# SQLAlchemy MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to use SQLALchemy MySQL ON_DUPLICATE_KEY_UPDATE() function, but it is not working as expected.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dml import Insert 

new_record={'id': 'val1', 'col1': 'new val'}

# Here id is the primary key
# my_table is a Table object
Insert(my_table).on_duplicate_key_update(new_record)
```

This code works without throwing an error, but the existing record in the table with primary key value `'val1'` is not being updated.

I looked into SQLAlchemy documentation about [on duplicate key update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dml.Insert.on_duplicate_key_update), but I am not able to understand how to call the function.

Comment: Is the provided example all? If so, then you've not executed tje created statement, and the insert is missing the values it should attempt to insert first.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that you've only created, and discarded, an insert statement object. In order to execute it you have to pass it to one of the `execute()` methods of SQLAlchemy. The statement is also lacking the values to first try and insert.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dml import Insert 

new_record = {'id': 'val1', 'col1': 'new val'}

# Here id is the primary key
# my_table is a Table object
stmt = Insert(my_table).values(new_record)
stmt = stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(col1=stmt.inserted.col1)

# This will actually execute the statement
engine.execute(stmt)
```